# Product of a list

Tags: python, list, product

I am using the following code to find the list of primes, but I also need to be able to find the product of the list created.  I don't know where to start.

```
def list_of_primes(x):
    primes = [2, 3]

    n = primes[-1] + 2

    while len(primes) < x:
        for p in primes:
            if n % p == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes.append(n)

        n += 2

    return (primes)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either maintain a variable that stores the *running product* or do something like

```
reduce(operator.mul, primes)  # product of elements in `primes`
```

(using [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) with [`operator.mul`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.mul))

Performance-wise, you shouldn't see a large gap between these two approaches for any reasonably sized list; you should use whichever makes more sense in the context of your program.